All categories are missing in the Global Themes menu on Kubuntu?
How can I resolve this error? When I try to open the global theme and select 'Get New Global Theme,' this error appears. "All categories are missing."

A lot of users (old and new) have this issue and there seems to be no solution so far: https://discuss.kde.org/t/global-theme-all-categories-missing/24747/22

There is an issue with your categories. To solve it, Open the following file
nano /usr/share/knsrcfiles/lookandfeel.knsrc

And change
Categories=121

With
Categories=Global Themes (Plasma 5)

Hope this solves your issue.
